# IE login issue with ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, iis, forms-authentication, internet-explorer

I have an ASP.NET webapp (on Win 2k3) that uses form authentication. For some reason, when a user logs in with Internet Explorer, the site either freezes or throws an error (such as `"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0"`).

This doesn't make any sense because I can login with Firefox and Chrome successfully.

Any ideas?

**Update**

Just found out this only happens when the login page is in an `IFrame`. IE doesn't persist the login cookie. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: would it be in IE6, 7 and 8? and when IE8 is running in IE8 standards mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue actually occurred because IE does not persist cookies or sessions created within an IFrame so the ProfileCommon could not be created.

Basically what I did was add the following header before the login procedure:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p","CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
```

The solution is posted here: http://adamyoung.net/IE-Blocking-iFrame-Cookies

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have:

.NET 3.5 SP1: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en

Chart Controls: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&displaylang=en

installed on your server. It is odd that FF and Chrome are not throwing the yellow screen of death.

**EDIT:** For kicks, can you copy the System.Web.DataVisualization into the /bin folder of your application on the web app?

Comment: Nope. That didn't help either.